# Cooked corn kernels, but not from corn cob

Tags: substitutions, corn, popcorn

In making a Mexican Polenta casserole, I need cooked corn kernels. Is is it possible to make this from the same stuff I would use to make popcorn? (Not the ones that come in microwaveable bags, just the raw corn kernels).

If not, could I possibly substitute it with something else?